# Вычисление пикселей от борта формы и отправка через POST запрос

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Хочу понять, как посчитать размеры в пиксялях от борта формы (красные стрелочки на рисунке) и размер самого окна Channel 1 и Channel 2 и отправить их в двух разных POST-запросов через AJAX. В этоге мне надо передать такие значение - `<channel> <hstart (пиксели когда начинается channel1 сверху)> <hsize (размер окна hight)> <vstart (пиксели когда начинается channel1 с лева[всегда с лева считается])> <vsize (размера окна width)>`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Snap to element or grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        .draggable2 {
            width: 90px;
            height: 80px;
            padding: 5px;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            font-size: .9em;
            margin-left: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 300px;
        }

        .draggable3 {
            width: 90px;
            height: 80px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            font-size: .9em;
            margin-left: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 120px;
            top: 300px;
        }

        .ui-widget-header p,
        .ui-widget-content p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        /* Разрешение экрана нужно получать */

        #snaptarget {
            height: 270px;
            width: 480px;
        }

        .ui-resizable-helper {
            border: 2px dotted #000000;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable2").draggable({
                snap: ".ui-widget-header",
                snapMode: "outer"
            }); /* Перемещение объекта */
            $("#draggable2").resizable({
                helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                containment: "#snaptarget"
            }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
            $("#draggable3").draggable({
                snap: ".ui-widget-header",
                snapMode: "outer"
            }); /* Перемещение объекта */
            $("#draggable3").resizable({
                helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                containment: "#snaptarget"
            }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">

</div>

<br style="clear:both">



<div id="draggable2" class="draggable2 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 1</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable3" class="draggable3 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 2</p>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Отправить AJAX'ом? Это важно в данной ситуации.

Comment: @smellyshovel обновил немного вопрос и да.

Comment: Я понял. Просто уже начал писать код, там немного не то получилось, что вы требуете теперь. Сейчас перепишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Snap to element or grid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
    .draggable2 {
        width: 90px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 300px;
    }

    .draggable3 {
        width: 90px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 300px;
    }

    .ui-widget-header p,
    .ui-widget-content p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Разрешение экрана нужно получать */

    #snaptarget {
        height: 270px;
        width: 480px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .ui-resizable-helper {
        border: 2px dotted #000000;
    }

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#draggable2").draggable({
            snap: ".ui-widget-header",
            snapMode: "outer",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,1);
            }
        }); /* Перемещение объекта */
        $("#draggable2").resizable({
            helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
            containment: "#snaptarget",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,1);
            }
        }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
        $("#draggable3").draggable({
            snap: ".ui-widget-header",
            snapMode: "outer",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,2);
            }
        }); /* Перемещение объекта */
        $("#draggable3").resizable({
            helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
            containment: "#snaptarget",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,2);
            }
        }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
    });

    function getPosSize(EL,channel){
        var Rect=EL.getBoundingClientRect();
        var papa=snaptarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        document.querySelector('#chan_'+channel).innerHTML='channel '+channel+': top: '+(Rect.top-papa.top)+'px, right: '+(papa.right-Rect.right)+'px, bottom: '+(papa.bottom-Rect.bottom)+', left: '+(Rect.left-papa.left)+', width: '+EL.offsetWidth+'px, height: '+EL.offsetHeight+'px.'
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">
<div id="chan_1"></div>
<div id="chan_2"></div>
</div>

<br style="clear:both">



<div id="draggable2" class="draggable2 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 1</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable3" class="draggable3 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 2</p>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Ну а отправку можно запихать в эту же функцию (getPosSize)

Comment: Плюс за `getBoundingClientRect()`, забыл о нем. Хотя тут надо именно в определенном формате передать, так что не факт, что он подойдет.

Comment: попробовал ваш код для начала, он выдает мне такие значения - `channel 1: top: 97px, right: 189px, bottom: 18, left: 6, width: 287px, height: 157px.` получается, он считает с двух сторон и сам элемент?

Comment: @Insider со всех четырех сторон относительно snaptarget + свою ширину и высоту

Comment: @smellyshovel Нужно ток навесить обработчик - отправка только когда все значения положительные(не минусовые)

Comment: @Insider Да, именно так. Это довольно универсальное свойство, только парсить потом придется его, чтоб под ваш формат подогнать.

Comment: @iMacrosSales а как будет только с одной стороны (вверх и слева)? Не совсем понимаю вашу function

Comment: @Insider как то вот так: function getPosSize(EL,channel){
         var Rect=EL.getBoundingClientRect();
         var papa=snaptarget.getBoundingClientRect();
   alert('top: '+(Rect.top-papa.top)+'px\nleft: '+(Rect.left-papa.left)+'px');
        }

Comment: @Insider papa - это серый div, Rect - елемент, с которым проводятся манипуляции. По поводу координат в окне/документе и  getBoundingClientRect() вот два мануала : [координаты в окне](http://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates), [координаты в документе](http://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates-document)

Comment: @iMacrosSales при вашем последнем варианте, пересылается ведь только координаты положения окна, а что на счет размера окна, как его получить?

Comment: @Insider 
EL.offsetWidth и EL.offsetHeight.

вот с размерами: 
function getPosSize(EL,channel){
         var Rect=EL.getBoundingClientRect();
         var papa=snaptarget.getBoundingClientRect();
   alert('top: '+(Rect.top-papa.top)+'px\nleft: '+(Rect.left-papa.left)+'px\nwidth: '+EL.offsetWidth+'px\nheight: '+EL.offsetHeight+'px');
        }

Comment: @iMacrosSales большое спасибо, буду пробовать и понимать ваш код)

Comment: @Insider Пожалуйста)) Еще один нюанс: в моем примере координаты берутся относительно видимой части окна, то есть без учета прокрутки. В ссылке "координаты в документе" есть готовая функция, которая будет учитывать текущую прокрутку документа.

Answer (score 2):

1. Находим нужные элементы:
   *Vanilla JS*

> `let drugables = document.querySelectorAll(".druggable");`

2. Найдем на странице форму `#for-druggables` и динамически создадим нужное количество скрытых полей:
   *Vanilla JS*

> ```
> form = document.querySelector("#for-druggables");
>
> for (dg of druggables) {
>   let elem = document.createElement("INPUT");
>   elem.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
>   elem.setAttribute("name", `dg-${dg.id}`);
>   elem.setAttribute("value", `${dg.offsetLeft}, ${dg.offsetTop}`);
>   form.appendChild(elem);
> }
> ```

3. Теперь у нас есть на странице форма, заполненная `hidden` полями, содержащими значение формата `отступ_слева, отступ_сверху`. Осталось отправить ее. Ловим событие отправки (например, это может быть клик на кнопку `#send`):
   *Vanilla JS*

> ```
> let send = document.querySelector("#send");
>
> send.addEventListener("click", function() {
>   form.submit();
> });
> ```

4. Осталось отправить AJAX'ом. Тут я расписывать не буду, примеров полно, нужно только поискать. Только подкину идейку, как организовать:
   *JQuery*

> ```
> form.on("submit", function() {
>   sendAjax();
>   return false; // чтобы не отправилось обычным способом.
> });
> ```

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. Сейчас формат данных надо подогнать только, который отправляться будет. То есть насколько я понял, надо отправить отступ слева, отступ сверху, высоту и ширину элемента. Верно?

Comment: да, только одного из элементов одновременно, при передвижении/увеличении.

Comment: @Insider Только одного, в тот момент, когда его увеличивают/передвигают?

Comment: при завершении движения или увеличения элемента в сером элементе, иначе ничего отправлять не должно.

Comment: @Insider в таком случае вам надо навесить 2 обработчика: `addEventListener("dragend", function() {});` и такой же, только `resize`. Единственная проблема - это что я не нашел обработчика именно под завершение ресайза, вполне вероятно, что он будет отправляться постоянно, пока его держат.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы навешивать на кнопку `#send`

Comment: в принципе можно и навешать на кнопку `#send`, как-то делал такое, оно отправлялось при получении новых `var` https://jsfiddle.net/ilja_grebel/33uh873h/

Comment: @Insider тут уже как ваша фантазия работает или ТЗ позволяет. Я предоставил алгоритм и немного кода. Подогнать под нужный формат можете в строке 7 второго участка кода. А остальное лучше делать именно так. Единственное только что с отправкой подумайте, как вам лучше будет.